# Can HMS support the 4.1 version of EMUI

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have a HUAWEI NXT AL10 device, it has the 4.1 version of EMUI, is it support for testing the HMS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which HMS service you want to test. Take Huawei Push Kit as an example,  EMUI 3.1 or later are supported. [Docs link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040060#section4559183416556).

[image]

But some functions also have other Restrictions on the EMUI version. You may refer to [Function Application Scope](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/restrictions-0000001050040064#section3910145815812).

And here are [EMUI Version-Dependent Features](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/emui-version-dependent-0000001050042515).